# string.indexof returns -1 when it shouldn't

Tags: apex

I'm getting the source string from Blob.ToString() method and the target string is hard coded.
string.indexof returns -1 even though the source string definitely contains the target string according to the logs.

the source string is being read from an uploaded file, so I'm wondering if there can be any encoding issues involved. doesn't blob.tostring() always return unicode?

Comment: Strings are always UTF-8. Is the match on multibyte characters (>127 ASCII)? Is the uploaded file itself UTF-8? Salesforce will not convert the encoding for you.

Comment: Yep, ended up to be an encoding issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up to be an encoding issue. Decoded the string and everything worked correctly. It's funny though that Dev Console displayed the string normally even though it was in a different encoding.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a little? We don't get solved questions about text encoding much and it might help other users in the future.

Comment: I'm parsing an Excel (xlsx) file and files inside of it are in UTF-16LE encoding. We had to convert them to UTF-8 encoding before Apex was able to successfully recognize that a string contains a substring.